# mysql sum up two columns

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables : stock_material_details and stock_consumed having a common filed item_id.
stock_material details has added_quantity as a column and stock_consumed as consumed_quantity as a column.

Everytime an item is added to stock it will be added in stock_material_details(table) under added_quantity.

Everytime an item is consumed, it will be added in stock_consumed under comsumed_quantity.
I want to write a query getting the total quantity available of a particular item by something like this:

```
select sum(a.added_quantity ) - sum(b.quantity_consumed) as available 
from stock_material_details a 
join stock_consumed b on a.item_id = b.item_id 
group by a.id
```

The above query so does not give the right result incase of multiple rows of data.Need some advice.

Comment: group by a.id...sorry

Comment: You can edit your own question to correct stuff like that (I did it for you this time)

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output - it will help us understand what you mean (cod I for one don't)

Answer (score 0):

select item_id, sum(a.added_quantity ) - sum(b.quantity_consumed) as available from stock_material_details a join stock_consumed b on a.item_id = b.item_id group by a.item_id

try to add "item_id" in select.

I try to use your code there but its not work.

try this one:

select item_id, SUM(added_quantity) - (Select SUM(quantity_consumed) from stock_consumed b where b.item_id = item_id) FROM stock_material_details Group by item_id

hope it work cos i am only compile it inside my mind

May The Force Be with You

Answer (score 0):

To mix two diffrent aggregates you're gonna need subqueries:

```
SELECT sum(a.sum_a) - sum(b.sum_b) AS available FROM
(SELECT a.item_id, sum(a.added_quantity ) AS sum_a
FROM stock_material_details a
GROUP BY a.id) AS a
JOIN
(SELECT b.item_id, sum(b.quantity_consumed) AS sum_b
FROM stock_consumed b
GROUP BY b.id) AS b
ON a.item_id = b.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not keeping track of each item in the results, it's impossible to tell what the numbers correspond to:

```
select a.item_id, sum(a.added_quantity ) - sum(b.quantity_consumed) as available 
from stock_material_details a 
join stock_consumed b on a.item_id = b.item_id 
group by a.id
```